# TableView not populating until I scroll past the cell when height of cell is changed

Tags: iphone, uitableview

What I've done is created a custom TableCell view that gets populated with information from an array of objects.  Each TableCell gets loaded in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

     Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
         cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
     }

     NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
     NSDictionary *rowData = (NSDictionary *)[self.surveys objectAtIndex:row];

     cell.info1.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"info1"]; 
     cell.info2.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"info2"]; 
     cell.info3.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"info3"];
     cell.otherInfo = [rowData objectForKey:@"otherInfo"];

     return cell;
}
```

In addition to this I specify a custom height for the cell here

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return 76.0;
 }
```

When the value for tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: is 76 it loads all the cells that I can see and they aren't ever blank.  Without changing anything else in the code I can modify the value in tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: and it will only show the first cell value when the view is loaded.  As I scroll down they are refreshed with a value as soon as their top edge hits the top of the screen.  When I get back up to the top and stretch the view so that it bounces back the bottom ones will disappear.

As far as I can tell, the change in height somehow affects how they are loaded but I can't for the life of me see how.

Comment: Does this also happen if you use UITableViewCells instead of your custom Cell?

Comment: It does not happen if it's a UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified a height in the custom cell .xib that was different than the one I was specifying in code.  Once this was changed to match the size specified in the code the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to pay attention to isn't just the size of the Custom table view cell's height but also the height of other sub views as well.

I had this problem when one of my UIImageView objects was higher than the cell height it would cause this very same problem.

Thanks for the post as it helped me sort out my issue too. +1  (wont let me vote up or I would, sorry)